# Joomla, Display a module that are not assigned to any position

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm new to Joomla and i need to show a module (joomla 3.x) that is not assigned to any positions.

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('find_a_story');
foreach( $modules As $mod ){
echo  $mod->content;
}
```

I figured out the above code to display modules from a position, But how will i display a module that is not assigned to any Position but published ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [JModuleHelper/getModule](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule) helper class documentation.

Using example 2 you could get the module you need based on type and name:

```
  jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
  $module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mainmenu', 'Resources' );
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r( $module );
  echo '</pre>';
```

Good Luck!